# Pandas - Sum up previous values of a column

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas, I'm trying to sum up all previous values of a column. In SQL I did this by joining the table to itself, so I've been taking the same approach in pandas, but having some issues.

Original Data Frame

```
         TeamName  PlayerCount   Goals   CalMonth
    0    A         25            126     1
    1    A         25            100     2
    2    A         25            156     3
    3    B         22            205     1
    4    B         30            300     2
    5    B         28            189     3
```

Code

```
    prev_month = np.where(df3['CalMonth'] == 12, df3['CalMonth'] - 11, df3['CalMonth'] + 1)

    df4 = pd.merge(df3, df3, how='left', left_on=['TeamName','CalMonth'], right_on=['TeamName', prev_month])
    print(df4.head(20))
```

Output

```
         TeamName  PlayerCount_x Goals_x CalMonth_x 
    0    A         25            126     1
    1    A         25            100     2
    2    A         25            156     3
    3    B         22            205     1
    4    B         22            300     2
    5    B         22            189     3

    PlayerCount_y Goals_y CalMonth_y 
    NaN           NaN     NaN
    25            126     1
    25            100     2
    22            NaN     NaN
    22            205     1
    22            100     2
```

The output is what I had in mind, but what I want now is to create a column that is YTD and sum up all Goals from previous months. Here are my desired results (can either include the current month or not, that can be done in an additional step):

```
         TeamName  PlayerCount_x Goals_x CalMonth_x 
    0    A         25            126     1
    1    A         25            100     2
    2    A         25            156     3
    3    B         22            205     1
    4    B         22            300     2
    5    B         22            189     3

    PlayerCount_y Goals_y CalMonth_y Goals_YTD
    NaN           NaN     NaN        NaN
    25            126     1          126
    25            100     2          226
    22            NaN     NaN        NaN
    22            205     1          205
    22            100     2          305
```

Comment: I think you just need a `cumsum()`. `df.groupby('TeamName')['Goals'].cumsum().shift()` as @Boud?

Comment: And maybe a groupby teamname

Comment: Thank you @Psidom @Boud! That worked.

Comment: Thanks folks for the answer even though it's in the comment. `.shift()` is cool, never knew about it before.